# Question marks in errors in Android Studio while trying to build

Tags: java, android

This is a super noob question but I tried to search the issue but can't find an answer.
Here's the error messages:

> C:\GoogleDrive\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\net\apastro\www\myapplication\MainActivity.java
>   Error:(20, 9) ??: ????? ??:   ?? Log ??: ? MainActivity Error:(25, 9)
>   ??: ????? ??:   ?? Log ??: ? MainActivity Error:(31, 9) ??: ????? ??: 
>   ?? Log ??: ? MainActivity Error:(37, 9) ??: ????? ??:   ?? Log ??: ?
>   MainActivity 4 ??? Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJava'. Compilation failed; see the compiler error
>   output for details.

I have `English(US)` setup in my Region and Language settings, and my *Language for non-unicode program* is `English(US)` as well.